# Admin widgets rtl support

Tags: netlify-cms

is it possible to change the css of an existing widget so it will support rtl?
I was thinking of creating a custom widget from the existing widget and just change the css but couldn’t find the widget code.

Answer (score 0):

All official Widget code is located here.
https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/tree/master/packages

Widgets are usually divided into "Editor" and "Preview" implementations, and you can customize the React Components that each generates. I'm not familiar with RTL, so I could be wrong, but if that can be done with just a CSS change, then you can probably do what you want to do.
https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/custom-widgets/